# Does navigation graph supports theme?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-theme, android-jetpack-navigation

I have multiple themes in my android application. Now in navigation_graph or mobile_navigation (whatever you called it), I am not getting theme changing opposition as we have in layout.[image]